# How delete children and still display parents with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to design a wishlist page but contrary to the traditional wishlist page we used to see I have decided to design one that contains wish items, so a user can create something like a wishlist folder then can decide to add his wish items in it or in them. I have two tables "wishlist" and "wishitems". The problem now I think should be from my query, a wishlist doesn't display if it has no related item in the "wishitems" table which I don't want. I want wishlists to display even if they don't have items in them. Can anyone help me please?

```
/**
 * Get Wishlists information by $userId.
 *
 * @param int $userId user session Id.
 * @return array Result of fetch.
 */
function getWishlist($userId): array
{
    try {
        $db = createConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM wishlist w
                LEFT JOIN wishitems wi ON wi.wishlistID = w.wishlistID
                LEFT JOIN products p ON wi.product_id = p.product_id
                LEFT JOIN images i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
                WHERE wi.user_id = :userId AND w.status = "1" AND imgPrimary = 1
                AND i.imgPath LIKE "%-tn%" AND wi.status = "1"
                ORDER BY w.wishlistID, w.date_created, wi.wishitemID DESC';            
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $wishlists = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $wishlists;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage()) ;
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving your `wi` conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `LEFT JOIN` clause.

Comment: @Delvin, hello please, how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN wishitems wi ON wi.wishlistID = w.wishlistID AND wi.user_id = :userId AND wi.status = '1'` .  Otherwise, your `WHERE` condition expects these values in the result set and null wishitems will fail the criteria.

Comment: NOTE:  you should also move the condition on the `images` table out of the `WHERE` clause.